# Dust partials rendering error in DocPad

Tags: dust.js, docpad

I'm using DocPad with docpad-plugin-consolidate and dustjs-linkedin.

My document file is src/documents/test.html.dust:

```
---
layout: ltest
---
Main content!
```

The following template src/layouts/ltest.html.dust works fine:

```
Content is {content}
```

I want to use [dust partials](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#wiki-Partials) in my layout template in the following way:

```
{>"header"/}
Content is {content}
{>"footet"/}
```

And place templates header.dust and footer.dust somewhere nearby. But I got an error:

> warning: Something went wrong while rendering: ltest.html.dust
>
> A task's completion callback has fired when the task was already in a completed state, this is unexpected
>
> warning: Something went wrong while rendering: test.html.dust
>
> A task's completion callback has fired when the task was already in a completed state, this is unexpected
>
> error: An error occured:
>
> Error: A task's completion callback has fired when the task was already in a completed state, this is unexpected

How to fix this error?

**UPD1.**
I created the simplest example to show the error (on Windows):

- _http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/x64/node.exe
- _http://nodejs.org/dist/npm/npm-1.4.3.zip
- npm install docpad@6.64
- mkdir test
- cd test
- docpad run
- ; No Skeleton (20) selected; exit after run
- docpad install consolidate
- npm install dustjs-linkedin
- docpad run
- ; visit _http://localhost:9778/test.html

Here are the files:
**src/documents/test.html.dust**

```
---
layout: ltest
---
Main content!
```

**src/layouts/ltest.html.dust**

```
Content: {content}
```

Until now everything works fine.

But with the following files everything goes wrong.

**src/layouts/ltest.html.dust**

```
{>"src/layouts/header.dust"/}
Content: {content}
```

**src/layouts/header.dust**

```
This is header
```

There are no errors, but output has no transformations. 
With debugger I found that (in dust.js 753) the function   Chunk.prototype.partial is called with proper parameters and processed fine, but result is lost somewhere.

So the problem is that DocPad failed to work with partials files in dust templates.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the header and footer templates?

Also, you have a typo in ltest.html.dust where it says "footet" instead of "footer".  Don't know if that will make a difference though.

Comment: I updated the original question and added a simplest error example.